# Programmatically change hostname of a newly created AWS instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am able to create an EC2 instance(Amazon Linux) using AWS Java SDK:

```
RunInstancesRequest runInstancesRequest = new RunInstancesRequest()
                .withInstanceType(InstanceType.valueOf("T2Micro"))
                .withImageId("ami-12345abc")
                .withMinCount(1)
                .withMaxCount(1)
                .withSecurityGroupIds("some-group")
                .withKeyName("my-key")

RunInstancesResult runInstancesResult = ec2.runInstances(runInstancesRequest);
```

Now I want the `hostname` of the thus created server to be changed as well, programmatically. Manually it is possible through this [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-hostname.html). I want to automate this, so I try using the [user data shell scripts](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html#user-data-shell-scripts) as:

```
RunInstancesRequest runInstancesRequest = new RunInstancesRequest()
                .withInstanceType(InstanceType.valueOf("T2Micro"))
                ......
                .withUserData(getUserDataScript());
RunInstancesResult runInstancesResult = ec2.runInstances(runInstancesRequest);

private static String getUserDataScript() {
        String str = "#!/bin/bash\n" +
                     "sudo sed -i -e 's/[before]/after/' /etc/sysconfig/network\n" + 
                     "sudo init 6";
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(str.getBytes());
}
```

The trouble now is that I can no longer log in to the instance so created. Just gives a plain `connection refused` error. Checked the key and every detail - I'm able to log in if I don't provide the user data script.

Am I changing the hostname correctly? Is there any other way to automate this?

Comment: Update: Now I am able to log in but it takes roughly around 15 minutes - too high a value for me to wait when creating the instance in my program

Answer (score 3):

when you run `sudo init 6` you do a reboot which can take some time, thats why you cannot logged in right away;

what you can try is to run the `hostname` command to directly use the new hostname so script will be something like

```
    String str = "#!/bin/bash\n" +
                 "sudo sed -i -e 's/[before]/new_hostname/' /etc/sysconfig/network\n" + 
                 "sudo echo 'new_hostname' >> /etc/hostname" +
                 "sudo hostname new_hostname";
```

note : I did not fully test this but I expect it should take the new_hostname without restart so it should allow you to connect - depending your flavor of linux distro it can be a bit different, I suggest you first logged in normally to the instance and run the command to make sure ti works on your linux distribution

Comment: Nice suggestion but sadly it doesn't work on Amazon Linux without restart